# How to add vertex image in mxGraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I am creating a toolbar in mxGraph using javascript. From toolbar I have set some images like triangle and dragging and dropping those images into my graph div area. I am adding these images like this

```
addVertex('rounded.gif', 100, 40, 'shape=rounded');
```

Now I wanted to add external vertex image like car, laptop. Please someone suggest me how to do this. instead of **shape=rounded** what I have to give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style key for an image is `image` and the value any URL. i.e.

```
image=https://www.jgraph.com/assets/img/drawlogo32.png
```

You can find a list of all styles from the diagrams linked in [this post](https://support.draw.io/display/DOB/2016/04/28/draw.io+Cell+Styles).